# How to prevent useEffect to be fired up in some events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

Halo guys, I would like to ask a frustating problem for me :'(

What if we don't want to trigger useEffect in some events for the same state. For example lets say I have a state called "myState" and I have put myState in useEffect's dependency. In button1 I want to update myState which will trigger useEffect, in button2 I want also update myState but I don't want to trigger the useEffect

Is it possible to prevent useEffect to be fired up such I just described?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please show us some code ? But generally speaking if I have to update a state inside a useEffect, I would just use an if statement. When you click on button1 you pass a bool = true as a parameter, when you click on button 2 you pass false, and then you just do if(bool) update(state).

Comment: why you don't use two different states for different buttons ?

Comment: Have a separate state that only one button sets, check that value in a condition in the effect, and then reset it after the effect is complete.

Comment: hi @Emilien .  The code example is in the answer , answered by Layhout 

there are 2 buttons that would change the the same state (myState) , but only one button is intended to trigger the useEffect . 

Layhout 's answered is good , but if you have another solution I will be glad to know :)

Comment: hi @PetePearl , I'm intended to change the same state by using different buttons

Just like Layhout's answered , I want one button will trigger the useEffect , but the other button won't .  Layhout 's answered is good but do you have another approach? :)

Answer (score 0):

Write UseEffects separately, you can keep on stacking them on one above others if you want to run them independantly

Answer (score 0):

in your state, you should have some kind of a breaker for useEffect. in my example i named it `stopUseEffect`. if i don't want the useEffect to run, i will set `stopUseEffect` to `true`. then in useEffect, first thing to do is to check the breaker, does breaker allow it to run or not (`if(myState.stopUseEffect) return;`):

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

const Test = () => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState({content: 0, stopUseEffect: false});
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(myState.stopUseEffect) return;
    
    console.log("useEffect ran! myState's content:", myState.content)
  }, [myState])

  return <div>
    <button onClick={() => setMyState(p => ({...p, content: p.content + 1, stopUseEffect: false}))}>btn 1, this button will trigger useEffect.</button> <br/>
    <button onClick={() => setMyState(p => ({...p, content: p.content + 1, stopUseEffect: true}))}>btn 2, this button will NOT trigger useEffect.</button>
</div>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Test />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi @Layhout , your answered is very good. it almost meet my expectation :)

I still wonder if there's any callback solution just like setState in Class Component

Comment: `setMyState` is a function that accept a callback function.

Comment: [useState doc](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useState#usestate)

Comment: sorry, i started learning react with function component, so i know nothing about class component.